# stringify bash array to json string

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm new to bash and I have a bash script with a variable that is an array called 'output'

I'd like to convert the bash array to a JSON string. for example:

original array:
`output = ['one', 'two']`

desired output:
`'["one","two"]'`

I have tried the following:

```
"$(jq -c -n '$ARGS.positional' --args "${output[@]}")"
```

but that seems to wrap the array inside another set of square brackets:

```
'["[\"one\",\"two\"]"]'
```

which is not what I want.

also, I'd like to assign the JSON string to a variable.

I also saw that I can do this:

```
echo '{"foo" : "bar"}' | jq -R .
```

but I dont know how to use my variable 'output' instead of the hard-coded object. Also, not sure how to assign the result of that to a variable

EDIT

here's the bash script:

```
service_list_json="$(jq -c -n '$ARGS.positional' --args "${output[@]}")"
```

EDIT 2

ok, I think I might be seeing where the issue is. the original array looks like this:

```
'["one","two"]'
```

i'm guessing the extra set of quotes around the array are causing it to be treated like a string?

Comment: `output=(one two); echo "$(jq -c -n '$ARGS.positional' --args "${output[@]}")"` results in `["one","two"]` for me. I'm not sure where you're getting your escaped brackets from. Can you post a complete bash snippet (it should be just a few lines)?

Comment: afaik bash doesn't have a built-in json parser. I would suggest creating a small php script or something that has built-in json parsing and just pass it to the php script to return it for your bash script

Comment: @CrayonViolent OP is using `jq`, which is a json util that does exactly what you suggest (and more! you should check it out if you're not familiar with it).

Comment: @yshavit ah I see. o/` the more you know o/`

Comment: @yshavit added an edit with the bash script i'm using

Comment: @yshavit sorry, i had copied something wrong over

Comment: @AbdulAhmad Please add a _complete_ snippet, including the initialization of `output` and the command that outputs the incorrectly escaped output. In the snippet you add, if I run that and then `echo "$service_list_json"`, I get `["one","two"]`. There's clearly something else going on for you, but I don't know what.

Comment: @yshavit one sec, sorry, i'm trying to create an example without using work code

Comment: @yshavit ok so I have added the original array, which looks like its wrapped by an extra set of quotes that I didnt notice originally. could that be the cause?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad Yeah, that isn't a bash array. Is the string actually that value, or does it look like that in the bash source? If it looks like that in the source, then the actual value is a string, `["one","two"]`. But it looks like that string is the output you want, so there's nothing you need to do. :-)

Comment: Is the input a _Bash array_ or a _string_ resulting from unescaping the  string `'["one","two"]'` or the input is the _string_ with the literal exact value `'["one","two"]'`? `original array: output = ['one', 'two']` presents an invalid bash code, resulting in `output: command not found` error. If the `${output[@]}` contains your input, please post the output of `declare -p output`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$output` is a string, not an array.

To declare a bash array, you need the following syntax:

```
output=(one two)
```

It then provides the expected result.

```bash
service_list_json=$(jq -c -n '$ARGS.positional' --args "${output[@]}")
echo "$service_list_json"
```

Output:

```
["one","two"]
```